# How to split the generated assets in seperated folders with Symfony Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I managed configure Webpack to output CSS and JS into respective sub-directories, i.e. public/assets/css and public/assets/js. However, I don't know how to do the same with Symfony Webpack Encore.

Comment: I havn't had the time too work with it but I noticed the [introducing webpack encore for asset managemenrt blogpost](https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-webpack-encore-for-asset-management) it has a config example to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory where assets are generated is defined  in the webpack.config.js file with  `.setPublicPath('/build')`.

I am not sure but since webpack is supposed to help you "not to care about generated assets" what is your need to split js/css files in sub folder ?